# Does wildfly provides the capability for credential reference to use a mask password in standalone.xml?

Tags: java, wildfly

I'm trying to use a mask password for the credential store (not for the aliases/credentials stored inside) in standalone.xml

It is currently configured like this;

```
<credential-stores>
    <credential-store name="testStore" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir" location="test.jceks" create="true">
        <credential-reference clear-text="storepass"/>
    </credential-store>
</credential-stores>
```

But I'm looking for capability use a mask password with salt and iteration, something like

```
 <authentication-configurations>
       <configuration name="masked-config">
           <set-user-name name="Guest"/>
           <credentials>
               <masked-password iteration-count="100" salt="12345678" masked-password="/Nym2s/dssMrabfdIGsZfQ=="/>
           </credentials>
           <sasl-mechanism-selector selector="PLAIN"/>
       </configuration>
   </authentication-configurations>
```

That is, use a mask password instead of clear text for credential store.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does.

```
<credential-stores>
    <credential-store name="test" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir" location="test.jceks" create="true">
        <credential-reference clear-text="MASK-J.UbqnPr9LQMe9dkgMERGG8C.B1Neb6CwihvAlHYjYxCTUn8gETT80JRPTi/vcXx9;uoFwaATR;100"/>
 </credential-store>
</credential-stores>
```